# How do I reproduce this JQuery ajax with Dojo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dojo

How do I reproduce this JQuery AJAX call using only Dojo Toolkit?

```
$.ajax({  
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/user/get", 
    data: JSON.stringify(requestParam),  
    type: "POST", 
    beforeSend: function(xhr) 
    {  
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  
    },
    success: function(user)
    {      
    }
});
```

I've tried using this code to no avail:

```
var xhrArgs = 
{
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/user/get",
    postData: dojo.toJson(requestParam),
    handleAs: "text",
    load: function(user)
    {
    },
    error: function(error)
    {
    }
}
var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

The server returns : `415 - The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().`

I use Spring MVC on the server side if that matters.

Comment: does the jquery version working with your app?

Comment: @FikriMarhan yep, perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the response from your server is going to be JSON, then Fikri is correct in that you will want to set `handleAs` to `"json"`.  However, that's not your main problem right now.

In the jQuery version of your code, you are setting 2 headers.  You don't seem to be setting those in the Dojo version of your code.  To set headers, add a `headers` property to your code:

```
var xhrArgs = 
{
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/user/get",
    postData: dojo.toJson(requestParam),
    handleAs: "json",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    load: function(user)
    {
    },
    error: function(error)
    {
    }
}
```

Also, if you are using Dojo 1.8 or newer, use the new `dojo/request` API instead.

```
require(["dojo/request", "dojo/json"], function (request, JSON) {
    var promise = request.post("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/user/get", {
        data: JSON.stringify(requestParam),
        handleAs: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }).then(function (user) {
        // load callback
    }, function (error) {
        // error callback
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the `handleAs` key is set to `text`. Try changing it to `handleAs: 'json'`